# docker-compose.yml is invalid because: networks.traefik_proxy.external contains an invalid type, it should be a boolean, or an object

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

We're trying to get traefik running.
When calling `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` we get an error message saying:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> networks.traefik_proxy.external contains an invalid type, it should be a boolean, or an object

Any ideas for noobs on how to solve this? :)

Content of the file docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    container_name: "traefik"
    hostname: "traefik"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./config:/etc/traefik"
    # labels:
    #  - "traefik.enable=true"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(traefik.example.com) && (PathPrefix(/api) || PathPrefix(/dashboard))"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=default"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
    #  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=auth@docker"
    #  - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:pass" # Siehe Anleitung
    networks:
      - "traefik_proxy"
      - "default"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: "always"

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
      external:
      name: "traefik_proxy"
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: There are a number of formatting problems with your `docker-compose.yaml` that make it difficult to help (because maybe you just have a syntax problem, or maybe it's just a copy/paste problem). Please edit your question and make sure the formatting here matches your actual file.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. just realized it and edited it. Now it should represent the actual layout of the file's content.

Comment: It looks like `name:` under `external:` is mis-indented. It's supposed to be a key of the `external:` map, so it needs to moved over two spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was actually the problem with this file!